# Decimals not being picked up in SQL case expression

Tags: t-sql, case

I have a case expression and whole numbers are working fine but when it gets to the decimal it is returning null, so when @inputUnits = '1' and @unitInCase = 2 @setUnit = 'Two' but when @unitInCase = .1 @setUnit = NULL not sure what is happening.

```
DECLARE
    @inputUnits varchar(50),
    @unitInCase numeric,
    @setUnit varchar(50)

SET @inputUnits = '1'
SET @unitInCase  =  .1
SET @setUnit =
    CASE
        WHEN @inputUnits  = '1' THEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN @unitInCase= .1 THEN 'One' 
                WHEN @unitInCase= 2 THEN 'Two'
                WHEN @unitInCase= 3 THEN 'Three'
                WHEN @unitInCase = 4 THEN 'Four'
            END 
        WHEN @inputUnits = '2' THEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN @unitInCase= .1 THEN 'One' 
                WHEN @unitInCase = .2 THEN 'Two'
                WHEN @unitInCase= .3 THEN 'Three'
                WHEN @unitInCase= .4 THEN 'Four'
            END
    END
```

Comment: What do you think is stored in `@unitInCase int` when you try to put a 0.1 there?

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements. The tag yoiu have used ([tag:case]) also tells you this.

Comment: Why are you declaring `@inputUnits` as a `varchar(50)` here? If it's going to hold a numerical value why not use a numerical datatype? Or are you likely to need to store 100 quindecillion -1?

Comment: I was just adding an example for input units, the values will be varchars. T-SQL absolutely supports case statements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 
I have also tried numeric as well as decimal instead of int to the same result.

Comment: Your link leads to: Docs / SQL / Reference / Transact-SQL (T-SQL) Reference / Language elements / **Expressions**  / CASE. It states: "The CASE _expression_ has two formats ..." Where do you see _statement_? Does `case 42 when 0 then -1 end;` execute without an error?

Comment: I have updated it to expression, and I also changed it to numeric, which is what it should have been in the first place. I still don't get why I am receiving null back

Comment: You get `NULL` because that is the default value of a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types): "If no _Boolean_expression_ evaluates to TRUE, the Database Engine returns the _else_result_expression_ if an ELSE clause is specified, or a NULL value if no ELSE clause is specified." The value of `when Cast( 0.1 as Int ) = 0.1` is rarely `TRUE` and and you chose not to have an `else` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what type of numeric you need e.g., `numeric(10,2)` so your code should start with (say)

```
DECLARE
    @inputUnits varchar(50),
    @unitInCase numeric(10,2),
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 for info about numeric and decimal data types (which are synonymous). Broadly speaking, the first number represents the number of digits you wish to track (on both sides of the decimal point), whereas the second number is the number of digits after the decimal point.

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e85aa198eb18f7479698c03579ccef6) with the code before and after.

In the example below, it shows what happens if you don't set the scale and precision.

```
DECLARE @x numeric;
SET @x = 1.234567890;
SELECT @x;
-- Result is 1
```